# Override Backbone.sync partially

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is there any way to override Backbone.sync partially, say, only `create` and `update`, and leave `read` and `delete` to use native Backbone.sync?

Comment: I don't know backbone but can't you do `Backbone.sync.create = function() {};`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple as that:

```
// retain original sync with new name
Backbone.ajaxSync = Backbone.sync;

Backbone.customSync = function(method, model, option) {
    // Fallback for old sync method
    if (method == 'read' || method == 'delete') return Backbone.ajaxSync(method, model, option);

    // your custom code for other methods
    console.log('Custom sync for ' + method);
}

Backbone.sync = Backbone.customSync;
```

Comment: this is looking very promising but what do I return the `customSync` anonymous function?